# FFmpeg to transfer from bad media

Tags: ffmpeg, file-transfer

I have an SDcard that has two videos recorded from an old phone.  The media is bad and I have already run SpinRite and chkdsk, to fix the errors.  The files still fail to copy completely.

I can play some portion of the files in VLC player.  It plays about as far as File copy and TeraCopy before the copy job fails.
They and MP4 files.  I would like to use ffmpeg to transfer the portion of the video that will play out.  is `-i` the best parameter?

`ffmpeg -i H:\badfile.mp4 e:\portion.mp4`

Here is the output from mediainfo if that helps

`Complete name                            : H:\DCIM\badfile.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/3gp4)
File size                                : 422 MiB
Duration                                 : 3 min 46 s
Overall bit rate                         : 15.6 Mb/s
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings                          : CABAC / 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, RefFrames               : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=61
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 3 min 45 s
Bit rate                                 : 15.5 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 19.469 FPS
Minimum frame rate                       : 14.085 FPS
Maximum frame rate                       : 30.303 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.385
Stream size                              : 418 MiB (99%)
Title                                    : VideoHandle
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-09-17 13:18:06
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-09-17 13:18:06
mdhd_Duration                            : 225892`

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 3 min 46 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Nominal bit rate                         : 96.0 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 3.46 MiB (1%)
Title                                    : SoundHandle
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-09-17 13:18:06
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-09-17 13:18:06

Comment: I found a duplicate on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/556192/how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-encode-a-file-with-possible-error

Comment: Thanks. since -ss flag whill skip over known bad spots. Is there away that ffmpeg will automatically seek past every X seconds and try reading until bad, then seek for more?